# Rewite Ruby map into Java map

Tags: java, guava

I have this Ruby structure:

```
COUNTRIES = {
      'AF' => { :country => 'Afghanistan', :alpha => 'AFG', :number => '004' },
      'AT' => { :country => 'Austria', :alpha => 'AUT', :number => '040' }
}
```

What data structure I can use in order to make the same structure and find the proper value based on the key that I need? I tried this using Gualava:

```
Table<String, String, Integer> table = HashBasedTable.create();

table.put("Austria", "AUT", 040);
```

But how I can map the main key `AT`? Maybe using Table into Hashmap? But then how  I can get the values from the Hashmap using some inner key>

Comment: I'd create a unique class that contained `String country, alpha, number;` instead of forcing it onto a table or `Map<String, Map<String, String>>`. Far too cumbersome, and pretty inefficient to create entire map structures within maps.

Comment: Can you show me some example with other data structure?

Answer (score 3):

The idiomatic way to write that in Java is as follows:

```
public class Country {
    private final String country;
    private final String alpha;
    private final String number;
    // constructor and getters
}

Map<String, Country> map = new HashMap<>();
COUNTRIES.put("AT", new Country("Austria", "AUT", "040");
// etcetera
```

Personally, I would include the 2 letter codes as an extra field of `Country`:

- It avoids the need to do a "reverse lookup" to get the 2 letter code.
- It allows you to create secondary hash tables; e.g. to enable lookup by 3 letter country code.  For example:

  ```
   Map<String, Country> map2 = new HashMap<>();
   for (Country country: map.values()) {
       map2.put(country.getAlpha(), country);
   }

   // That could also be written as:
   // Map<String, Country> map2 = map.values().stream()
   //      .collect(Collectors.toMap(Country::getAlpha, Function.identity())

   map2.get("AUT");
  ```

It is possible to implement this using `Map<String, Map<String, String>>` but it is more cumbersome, less efficient and more fragile<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1 - Problems arise if there is a typo in either the code that builds the maps or that accesses then.  For instance, if you miss-typed "country" as "coumtry" in one of the map entries, the compiler wouldn't pick it up, and you are liable to get an unexpected NPE.</sup>

Comment: Can you show me how to make a query for a key for example if I use this method?

Comment: Can you give me an example of what you mean?

Comment: If I have the key "AUT" how I can make a query into the data structure and get the value "040"?

Comment: Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 2):

You could write your own class. (Constructor + Getter/Setter also there)

```
public class Country {
    private String country;
    private String alpha;
    private String number;
}
```

To store your objects of our class, you could use a map.

```
Map<String, Country> table = new HashMap<>();
table.put("AF", new Country("Afghanistan", "AFG", "004");
table.put("AT", new Country("Austria", "AUT", "040");
```

Comment: Is there some solution with data structure because i want to use the default methods for finding a key or a value?